# Does JAWS read ActiveX content?

Tags: javascript, html, activex

If JAWS does not read ActiveX content, how should I go about making this website 508 compliant?

Here is a code excerpt:

```
            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" FOR="posXUserForm" EVENT="ControlInitialized" >

                try {
                    posXUserForm.SchemaLoadObject.URL = "form.xsd";
                    posXUserForm.XMLDataLoadObject.URL = "form.xml";
                    posXUserForm.DesignDataLoadObject.URL = "form.sps";
                    posXUserForm.StartEditing();


                }catch(e) {
                    alert("Error loading form:" + e.name + "-" + e.message);
                }

            </SCRIPT>           
            <object id="posXUserForm"
                    name="posXUserForm"
                    CodeBase="<%=path%>/activex/AuthenticBrowserEdition.cab#Version=11,0,0,0"
                    Classid="clsid:B4628728-E3F0-44a2-BEC8-F838555AE780"
                    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    Sorry, please enable ActiveX to view this user form.
                <param name="ToolbarsEnabled" value="false" />
                <param name="BaseURL" value="<%=basePath%>files/forms/" />
            </object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the contents of FSDomSrv.ini, add a section something like this

```
[PoxUserForm using object tag]
DLLName=FSDomNodeMSAA
MappingFlags=96
StartString=PoxUserForm Start
EndString=PoxUserForm end
TagName=OBJECT
Param=classid|clsid:B4628728-E3F0-44a2-BEC8-F838555AE780
implementationFlags=7
InteractionModeFlags=7
```

In JAWS 9, with this section added JAWS should read 'PoxUserForm Start' when it enters your control and 'PoxUserForm End'as it leaves. To get information out of the control you will have to create an IAccessible implementation for your control and write JAWS script to extract the values you require.

This technique doesn't seem to work with JAWS 11 - I am currently trying to get some information from Freedom Scientific to find out how to fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is great information. I will try it out and let you know, but be advised I am using JAWS 11, not 9. :(

Comment: Actually, this solution seems to work PERFECTLY! And just to clarify: I am using JAWS 11, not 9.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Fran. I'll keep tweaking my JAWS 11 configuration to see if I can get this working on my machine. You may be able to help - are you using any special keypress to get JAWS 11 to read your control?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ActiveX.

Think about all the Firefox users.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. I'm looking to find the best way to make this website 508 compliant and JAWS continually skips over this.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use ActiveX.

Comment: Sadly, the website is already built. If I'm going to suggest that they do not use ActiveX, I'm going to need an alternative. :-P